# jQuery each loop output

Tags: jquery, html, each, weather

hi I got a question about how to use jQuery display all the data in a xml file with each loop, it just only display 1 single record now, thanks.
html code:

```
<label id="lbCity">City:<p id="city"></p></label>
<label id="lbDate"><p id="date"></p></label>
<label id="lbRain">Rain:<p id="rain"></p></label>
<label id="lbWind">Wind:<p id="wind"></p></label>
<label id="lbMin">Min:<p id="min"></p></label>
<label id="lbMax">Max:<p id="max"></p></label>
<label id="lbHumi">Humidity:<p id="humi"></p></label>
<label id="lbCloud">Cloud:<p id="description"></p></label>
```

[XML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBriV.jpg)

jQuery code:

```
   $(document).ready(function(e) {

        $("#Button").on('click', function(){

            loading(true);


            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url: url,
                dataType:'text', // type of the file format

                success: function(data){

                    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data);
                    var xml = $(xmlDoc);

                    $(xml).find('forecast time').each(function(){

                    $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attrib){
                    console.log( $($.parseXML(data)).find("country").text() );
                    $("#city").html( xml.find("name") );

                    $("#date").html( xml.find("time").attr("day") );
                    $("#min").html( xml.find("temperature").attr("min") + "&deg;C" );
                    $("#max").html( xml.find("temperature").attr("max") + "&deg;C" );   

                    });
                    });

                },

            });

        });
```

Comment: the problem is that you're setting each time the value of your labels using `html()`, try by replacing it with `append()`, you should see all the values inside your labels. If you want them separated recreate with js your html structure for each row and then append it to a container.

Comment: use $(this).find() instead of xml.find()